# How can I bind a "keydown" event to a jqgrid cell?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

## Question:

Can I bind a "keydown" event to a jqgrid cell?

*(Ultimately, the intent of the post/question is to solve an accessibility problem.)*

## Description of problem:

***Scenario:***

A user is traversing the cells of the grid with the arrow keys and he stops on a particular cell.
***Note***: he can use "arrow key" navigation between the jqgrid cells because the jqgrid "cellEdit" parameter is set to true (i.e., `cellEdit: true`).   He now presses the `<enter>` key over the cell he has stopped over.

What I want is to capture that resulting `<enter>` keydown/keyup event on that jqgrid cell, and do something with it.

--Up to now, my attempts to accomplish this have not worked.

***FWIW - The original issue that spawned my post:***  If there happened to be a `<button>` inside the cell that the user decided to stop on (i.e., as they were navigating the grid with the arrow keys), if the user then pressed the  key over that cell/button, nothing would happen.

*(Note: I already know that if you happen to `<tab>` to the `<button>` cell, you'll see that the button is focused and you can press the  `<enter>`  key to click it.   But, subsequent,  `<enter>`  presses fail to work.)*

-Therefore, I decided, as a workaround, that if I could at least capture the  keydown event, then, I might be able to fire a click event on the button - in order to achieve what I needed.

Thanks for your help!

*(And, please let me know if I need to further clarify, or provide other information)*

***For now, my jqgrid column model is defined like this:***

```
    -
    -
    -
    colNames: ['', 'city', 'postal code', 'VIEW'],
    colModel: [
        {name: 'id', label: "id", index: 'id', width: 100, hidden: true},
        {
            name: 'cityName', 
            label: "cityName", 
            index: 'cityName', 
            width: 100, 
            sortable: true,
            cellattr: function(){return 'tabindex="0"'}
        },
        {
            name: 'postalCode', 
            label: "postalCode", 
            index: 'postalCode', 
            width: 100, 
            sortable: true,
            cellattr: function(){return 'tabindex="0"'}
        },
        {
            name: 'view', 
            label: 'view', 
            index: 'view', 
            width: 100, 
            fixed: true,                          
            formatter: function() { return "<button tabindex='0' class='cellbtn' type='button'>View</button>";}
        }
    ],
    -
    -
    -
```

---

[image]

---

## A full **"standalone"** html example page

(i.e., you should be able to save to an HTML file, and run it)***

*Note:  Someone suggested that I try try an "editOptions"/"dataEvents" parameter solution (using the column model to capture a keypress/keydown/keyup event).  For now, I've commented out the code used to attempt this solution, because it did not work.*

Essentially, the point of supplying this page will be to provide illustration regarding navigating with the "arrow" keys.  If you run the page, you can then click on a cell, and then navigate around with the arrow keys.  Try stopping over the "button" cell and pressing the `<enter>` key... --you'll see that nothing happens, right now.

***Another update:***

I made a slight modification to the "loadComplete" function - and, now the button will maintain focus after being clicked via the `<enter>` key.  (thanks again, Oleg)

---

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>cellbutton click test</title>

            <!-- Import jQuery UI and jqGrid UI -->
            <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.13/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" />
            <link href="http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/themes/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

            <!-- Import jQuery jqGrid JS files -->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.src.js"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                    //...data for table
                    var localdata = [
                            {id: "1", cityName: "springfield", postalCode: "11111"},
                            {id: "2", cityName: "new york", postalCode: "22222"},
                            {id: "3", cityName: "huntington", postalCode: "33333"}
                        ];

                    $("#testgrid").jqGrid({
                        datatype: "local",
                        data: localdata,
                        cellsubmit: 'clientArray',
                        cellEdit: true,
                        colNames: ['', 'city', 'postal code', 'VIEW'],
                        colModel: [
                            {name: 'id', label: "id", index: 'id', width: 100, hidden: true},
                            {
                                name: 'cityName', 
                                width: 100, 
                                //editable: true,
                                cellattr: function(){return 'tabindex="0"'}
                            },
                            {
                                name: 'postalCode', 
                                width: 100, 
                                //editable: true,
                                cellattr: function(){return 'tabindex="0"'}
                            },
                            {
                                name: 'view', 
                                width: 100, 
                                fixed: true,                        
                                formatter: function() { return "<button tabindex='0' class='cellbtn' type='button'>View</button>";}
                            }
                        ],
                        rowNum: 10,
                        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                        pager: '#pager',
                        sortname: 'id',
                        //viewrecords: true,
                        height: "auto",
                        sortorder: "desc",
                        caption: "test",
                        rownumbers: true,
                        //loadonce: true, //otherwise, sort will reload data from server (i.e., erasing any client-side input that has not yet been posted)...
                        loadComplete: function() {
                            $("th[id^='testgrid_']").attr("tabindex", "0");

                            $(this).find("button.cellbtn").click(function (e) {
                                var rowid = $(this).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id");
                                $("<span>View button are clicked. The rowid=" + rowid +
                                  "<br/></span>").appendTo("#log");
                                setTimeout(function () 
                                {                                   
                                    $(e.target).focus();
                                }, 50);                           
                            });                     
                        },
                        afterEditCell: function (rowid) 
                        {
                            var $editControl = $("#" + rowid).find("input, select, textarea");
                            var events = $._data($editControl[0], "events"); // old jQuery: $editControl.data("events")
                            var originalKeydown;

                            if (events && events.keydown && events.keydown.length === 1) 
                            {
                                originalKeydown = events.keydown[0].handler; // save old

                                $editControl.unbind("keydown");
                                $editControl.bind("keydown", function (e) 
                                {
                                    var $viewButton;
                                    // we can do something before jqGrid process "keydown" event
                                    if (e.keyCode === 13 && e.target.id.split("_")[1] === "postalCode") 
                                    {
                                        $("<span>Enter are pressed(A)<br/></span>").appendTo("#log");
                                        setTimeout(function () 
                                        {
                                            $viewButton = $(e.target).closest("td").next("td").find("button.cellbtn");                                  
                                            $viewButton.focus();
                                        }, 50);                                 
                                    } 
                                    else 
                                    if (e.keyCode === 9 && e.target.id.split("_")[1] === "postalCode") 
                                    {
                                        $viewButton = $(e.target).closest("td").next("td").find("button.cellbtn");
                                    }
                                    originalKeydown.call(this, e);
                                    // we can do something after jqGrid process "keydown" event
                                    if (e.keyCode === 9 && $viewButton !== undefined) 
                                    {
                                        $("<span>Tab are pressed so that View button has focus.<br/></span>").appendTo("#log");
                                        setTimeout(function () 
                                        {
                                            $viewButton.focus();
                                        }, 50);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    $("#pager_left").hide();
                });            
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form id="form1">
                <div tabindex="0" id="gridx" class="editFormTable">
                    <table tabindex="0" id="testgrid"></table>
                    <div tabindex="0" id="pager" ></div>
                    <div id="log"></div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I've added the code for "editoptions/dataEvents" in the above example.  The code is "standalone", so, you should be able to simply copy it to an HTML file, and then run it.  So far, when I click on the "cityName" cell and then press any key - nothing happens.  Thx again for any help.

Comment: I've since removed/commented the code representing the "editoptions/dataEvents" solution, because I could not get it to work.  For now, the standalone example page will at least illustrate what I mean by "arrow key" navigation among the cells, and the fact that pressing the <enter> key has no effect - i.e., in that I have been unable so far to capture this key event.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly your question you want to do some actions before or after jqGrid process <kbd>Enter</kbd> key pressed during cell editing. jqGrid don't have any callback which can be used directly for the purpose. Nevertheless you can solve the problem relatively easy using "subclassing" of jQuery events.

First of all you can examine the source code of jqGrid and find out [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.5.2/js/grid.celledit.js#L88) which bind `keydown` event handler to any `<input>`, `<select>` or `<textarea>` child element in the `<td>` cell. *After* that (see [the lines](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.5.2/js/grid.celledit.js#L112-L115)) the callback `afterEditCell` and the event `jqGridAfterEditCell` will be called. So inside of `afterEditCell` callback for example you can examine event handles of bound to `<input>`, `<select>` or `<textarea>` to handle `keydown` event. You can save the original handle which are bound to jqGrid event handle, unbind it and replace it to your own callback. Inside of your event handle you can call the original handle of jqGrid, but you can do this conditionally and you can add some your actions before or after jqGrid processed `keydown` event. The corresponding code you will find in [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/cellEditEnter.htm). It uses the following `afterEditCell`:

```
afterEditCell: function (rowid) {
    var $editControl = $("#" + rowid).find("input, select, textarea"),
        events = $._data($editControl[0], "events"),
                 // old jQuery: $editControl.data("events")
        originalKeydown;

    if (events && events.keydown && events.keydown.length === 1) {
        originalKeydown = events.keydown[0].handler; // save old

        $editControl.unbind("keydown");
        $editControl.bind("keydown", function (e) {
            // we can do something before jqGrid process "keydown" event
            if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                $("<span>Enter are pressed.<br/></span>").appendTo("#log");
            }
            originalKeydown.call(this, e);
            // we can do something after jqGrid process "keydown" event
        });
    }
}
```

**UPDATED**: I am still not sure that I understand your requirements correctly, but I suppose that you need do some actions in the user pressed <kbd>Tab</kbd> in the field before "View" button (<kbd>Tab</kbd> pressed in `postalCode` column). You can set focus on the "View" button and if the user press <kbd>Enter</kbd> then `click` handler of the "View" button will be triggered. I think it's what you try to implement.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/cellEditEnter1.htm) demonstrate such behavior. It uses the following code:

```
$("#testgrid").jqGrid({
    ...
    loadComplete: function() {
        ...
        $(this).find("button.cellbtn").click(function () {
            var rowid = $(this).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id");
            $("<span>View button are clicked. The rowid=" + rowid +
              "<br/></span>").appendTo("#log");
        });
    },
    afterEditCell: function (rowid) {
        var $editControl = $("#" + rowid).find("input, select, textarea"),
            events = $._data($editControl[0], "events"), // old jQuery: $editControl.data("events")
            originalKeydown;

        if (events && events.keydown && events.keydown.length === 1) {
            originalKeydown = events.keydown[0].handler; // save old

            $editControl.unbind("keydown");
            $editControl.bind("keydown", function (e) {
                var $viewButton;
                // we can do something before jqGrid process "keydown" event
                if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                    $("<span>Enter are pressed.<br/></span>").appendTo("#log");
                } else if (e.keyCode === 9 && e.target.id.split("_")[1] === "postalCode") {
                    $viewButton = $(e.target).closest("td").next("td").find("button.cellbtn");
                }
                originalKeydown.call(this, e);
                // we can do something after jqGrid process "keydown" event
                if (e.keyCode === 9 && $viewButton !== undefined) {
                    $("<span>Tab are pressed so that View button has focus.<br/></span>").appendTo("#log");
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $viewButton.focus();
                    }, 50);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

The results of editing of the second row, pressing Tab in `postalCode` column and then pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> on "View" button looks like on the picture below

[image]

Comment: Hi Oleg - Thank you for attending to my question! To further explain: When a user clicks on a cell, the background of the cell turns yellow (I think this may represent a "selected" state). Anyway, with the cell in this "selected" state, if the user then hits the "<enter>" key, I would like to capture that event. If the user uses the "right arrow" key to move an adjacent cell (which now turns yellow) and presses the "<enter>" key, I would like to capture that event. (I think my idea is similar to putting an "onkeyup=" clause in the "<td>" tag). --Is this way of thinking to simplistic?

Comment: @sairn: You are welcome! You wrote that you would like to capture "<enter>" key, but you don't wrote what you need do in the corresponding event handler. It's unclear whether you want that jqGid process the event too (save the changes) or you need to deny it in some cases. In any way [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/cellEditEnter.htm) which I posted logged pressing of `<enter>` key and my code call `originalKeydown` owed by jqGrid. So one can make any actions before or after any key processing. One can skip processing of `keydown` by jqGrid if needed. One have full control.

Comment: Hi Oleg - My point of capturing the <enter> key event, was that I wanted to provide the user the "accessibility" of using the <enter> key emulate a mouse click on the cell. Kind of like how you can use "onCellSelect" to capture and handle a mouse click on a cell. But, of course, "onCellSelect" only works for mouse clicks. Is there a way to do something similar for key events (like "<enter>")?  In this case, I only want to handle the <enter> key event.  I dont have a need to edit/save the cell contents.

Comment: ...Ultimately, I'd like the user to also be able to hit the <enter> key when the cell containing the <button> is "selected" - which would "click" the <button>.

Comment: @sairn: I hope that I understand you correctly now. Look at the **UPDATED** part of my answer which provide [new demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/cellEditEnter1.htm).

Comment: Hi Oleg - you have been *very* generous with your time.  Thank you.   Please note - Your example actually illustrates exactly the issue that inspired my initial posting.  --Notice how when you tab to the button cell and click it - it only works the first time.  How should I overcome this?  How can I keep the button from losing focus so that it can be immediately clicked again (as in a "toggle")?  --Fwiw, one solution I had tried was to capture the click event in the HTML "td" so that I could programmatically click the button- but, the event seemed "blocked".   In any case, thanks again.

Comment: Hi Oleg - If it helps -  note my example (above). See how I tried to change it to re-focus the button after it is clicked (didnt work).

Comment: @sairn: You are welcome! Could you describe the exact test case which you mean? (one do 1, 2, ... Expected results... Instead of that one have the following...).

Comment: Hi Oleg (sorry to get back so late)... Using sample I provided in my post above [I updated it for you]:  SCENARIO A: (1) click on row#1/cell#1.  (2) use right arrow key to move "focus" to row#1/cell#3 [i.e., button cell].  (3) press the <enter> key [note how nothing happens]...  SCENARIO B: (1) use tab key to move to button cell.  (2) press <enter> key [button reacts - yay!].  (3) press <enter> key again [button does NOT react - darn].    Please let me know if I've been clear enough.  Thanks!

Comment: @sairn: Which web browser you used to test [my demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/cellEditEnter1.htm)? I used IE10 and Google Chrome 29. SCENARIO A: To step (2): **to move "focus" one have to use "Tab" or "Shift-Tab" instead of arrow key**. To step (3): After I press "Enter" key the text "View button are clicked. The rowid=3" will be shown at the bottom. So all works correctly.

Comment: Hi Oleg.  Unfortunately, I'm forced to use IE8 at the moment.  Do you think my browser is the issue, then?  FYI - I am successfully able to use the "right arrow" key to move the "focus" (i.e., the cell background changes to yellow ) from one cell to another.  NOTE: I have "edit" turned of for cell columns 1 and 2 in my version.  --Also, in SCENARIO #B, after I tab to the "button" cell, I can successfully press <enter> and the button clicks *the first time*.   But, when I press <enter> again, nothing happens.  Why does the button lose focus?  -How to prevent this?   Thanks

Comment: Hi Oleg - Thanks for your generous time and expertise.  My last question for you is how can I maintain focus on the button after the user presses <enter> so that they can immediately press <enter> again and get the same result. -For me the button loses focus after the 1st time <enter> is pressed - so that pressing <enter> the 2nd time does not work. If I understand you correctly, it sounds as if the 2nd time does not work due to the browser:  IE8. Can you confirm this?  (I'm awarding the bounty to you in any case in thanks for your generous time spent).   Thanks again.

Comment: @sairn: You are welcome! First about IE8: I have no IE8 so I just can't reproduce any test with IE8. I don't wrote that some problem exist in IE8. Because I have no IE8 I can't say nothing about it. Second jqGrid support **only Tab and Shift-Tab** (see [the lines](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.5.2/js/grid.celledit.js#L104-L105)) for movement of the cell editing "focus". If you want support arrows you need calls of `prevCell` or `nextCell` on keypress. Last: you can set any focus after pressing of "View" button with respect of `setTimeout(function () {$viewButton.focus();}, xxx);`

Comment: I modified the loadComplete slightly - using the info you provided - and the button now "maintains" focus: $(this).find("button.cellbtn").click(function (e) { var rowid = $(this).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id"); $("<span>View button are clicked. The rowid=" + rowid + "<br/></span>").appendTo("#log"); setTimeout(function () { $(e.target).focus(); }, 50); });  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can define individual events for every column in the definition of jqgrid using `dataEvents`. As mentioned in the [wiki](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules), its of type array and is a :

> list of events to apply to the data element; uses `$(”#id”).bind(type, [data], fn)` to bind events to data element.

```
 {name:"postalCode",index:"postalCode",width:80,align:"right",editable:true,sortable:true,
  editrules:{number:true},formatter:'integer',search: false,
  editoptions:{size:14,maxlength:14,
                dataEvents: [
                        {
                         type: 'keypress',
                         fn: function(e) {
                                           var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode; // to support all browsers
                                           //something on key press by manipulating above value

                                }
                        },
                        {  type: 'change',
                            fn: function(e) {
                            //something if value changed
                            }
                        }
                       ]}},
```

Comment: Hi Ajo - Thank you so much for your response.  I'm still having some trouble, however.  As an experiment I added this to the "cityName" column definition (in my example, above):                              editoptions: { dataEvents: [ 
                            {
                                type: 'keypress',
                                fn: function(e) 
                                {
                                    alert("key down event caught");
                                }
                            }]}

Comment: Intuitively, I would expect a keypress/keydown event to cause the "alert" to fire.  But, it does not.  What do I not understand about how the dataevent should work, do you think?  (thx again)

Comment: ...I'll add it to the example posted in my question, in case, you want to see how I coded it

Comment: Okay - I've added the code for "editoptions/dataEvents" in the above example.  The code is "standalone", so, you should be able to simply copy it to an HTML file, and then run it.  So far, when I click on the "cityName" cell and then press any key - nothing happens.  Thx again for any help.

Comment: @sairn perhaps i was not clear. this event can be called only when the cell is in edit mode, hence it is defined in edit options . Hope it helps

Comment: Hi Ajo - Based on your comment, I should probably re-phrase my original question, or post a new one.   Essentially, what I want to achieve is this:  when a user is traversing the cells of the grid and stops on a particular cell.  I want to capture the event when they now press the <enter> key over that cell.  The original issue: if there happened to be a button in that cell, the user pressing <enter> would do nothing.  So, I thought that if I captured the <enter> keydown event, I could at least fire off a click event for the button.  thanks again for your help.